# How do you get files from aws s3 bucket?

Tags: javascript, rhino, servicenow

I currently cannot put the aws-sdk package in servicenow. I need to get a file downloaded/ get the object from an s3 bucket but my code results only provide a list of everything inside the bucket. If I put the exact address of the object as the Endpoint, I get something along the lines of cannot verify canonical address

I've been able to get the aws4 package and cryptoJs package into servicenow.

```js
     var creds= { accessKeyId: 'access key' ,
      secretAccessKey: 'secretAccessKey'

       };

      var opts = {
      host: "mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com",
      path: '/',
      region: 'us-east-2',
      myService:'s3',
      myMethod: 'GET'
      };

       function getAmzDate(dateStr) {
      var chars = [":","-"];
      for (var i=0;i<chars.length;i++) {
        while (dateStr.indexOf(chars[i]) != -1) {
          dateStr = dateStr.replace(chars[i],"");
        }
      }
      dateStr = dateStr.split(".")[0] + "Z";
      return dateStr;
        }

        function getSignatureKey(Crypto, key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
      var kDate = Crypto.HmacSHA256(dateStamp, "AWS4" + key);
      var kRegion = Crypto.HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
      var kService = Crypto.HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
      var kSigning = Crypto.HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
      return kSigning;
        }

        var amzDate = getAmzDate(new Date().toISOString());
        var authDate = amzDate.split("T")[0];
        gs.log(amzDate);
        gs.log(authDate);


       var payload = '';
       var hashedPayload =  x_aws_sigv4.CryptoJS.SHA256(payload).toString();
       gs.log(hashedPayload);

       var canonicalReq =  opts.myMethod + '\n' +
       opts.path + '\n' +
       '\n' +
       'host:' + opts.host + '\n' +
       'x-amz-content-sha256:' + hashedPayload + '\n' +
       'x-amz-date:' + amzDate + '\n' +
       '\n' +
       'host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date' + '\n' +
        hashedPayload;

        var canonicalReqHash 
        =x_aws_sigv4.CryptoJS.SHA256(canonicalReq).toString();

       var stringTosign =  'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n' +amzDate + '\n' +authDate+'/'+ 
       opts.region+'/'+ opts.myService+'/aws4_request\n'+canonicalReqHash;

       var signingKey = getSignatureKey(x_aws_sigv4.CryptoJS, 
       creds.secretAccessKey, authDate, opts.region, opts.myService);

        var authKey = x_aws_sigv4.CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringTosign, signingKey);
        var authString  = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 ' +
        'Credential='+
        creds.accessKeyId+'/'+
           authDate+'/'+
        opts.region+'/'+
        opts.myService+'/aws4_request,'+
        'SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,'+
        'Signature='+authKey;

        var options = {
      headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' },

      };

      gs.log(authString);

      var rm = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2();
      for (var h in options.headers) {
        rm.setRequestHeader(h, options.headers[h]);
      }


      rm.setHttpMethod('GET');
      rm.setEndpoint('https://' + opts.host);
      rm.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authString);
      rm.setRequestHeader('Host', opts.host);
      rm.setRequestHeader('X-Amz-Date', amzDate );
      rm.setRequestHeader('x-amz-content-sha256', hashedPayload );
      var response = rm.execute();
      var body = response.getBody();
      gs.log(body.toString());
```

I'm supposed to get the actual file to automatically import it into servicenow

Comment: I would guess there are even more problems integrating CryptoJs and x_aws_sigv4, since they are made to run in a browser or on a nodeJS server.  On my instance i ran into "console.log(error)" and try catches, which did not show up in logs and the script ran "without problems". Check the scripts for "window", "navigator" and other typical objects.

Can you not a MID server for that?

Comment: in order for CryptoJS to work , you need to run the npm commands to build the file (basically take all its dependencies and make it into one script). x_aws_sigv4 is the application I created that holds these scripts (for some reason, it only works if you put it in a scoped app instead of a global app)

Comment: Global scope runs in compatibility mode, scoped apps in es5: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/london-application-development/page/script/JavaScript-engine-upgrade/concept/c_JS_modes.html